# Jquery thickbox print iframe - IE problem

Tags: iframe, printing, internet-explorer-9, thickbox

I'd like to print an iframe content that opens using thickbox with this code

```
<body onload="window.print()">
```

but in IE9 (only version IE I tested) the page sent to the the printer is the entire page where the iframe was launched. In Chrome everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body onload="window.focus();window.print()">
```